# HTTP PUT method returns 404 on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, http, file-upload, activex

I installed demo activeX on my web application which at the end try to upload file on server using PUT method. I'm using Windows 7.

There I get an error 404 File Not Found.

Can you please let me know what I should fix to make this working.

Answer (score 0):

The [`PUT`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) method will not automatically upload a file for you.

You need to write your web application to accept the `PUT` operation and save the file you are sending.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileupload.aspx) is one tutorial on uploading files. There are many around.

Also, see the [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) and [`HtmlInputFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czkya88e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) classes.

Comment: It's demo from LeadTools (http://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/CS/forums/29827/ShowPost.aspx - last post) and it should be working as it is. There is a lot of articles on the web, how to enable that in IIS6, but IIS7 is something completely different (really hate IIS7 interface!!!)